# How do you transfer a variable that is within a private method ActionPerformed to another method in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I created a graphical interface in a small program in Java. When you create the fields in the graphical interface, you have automatically created the actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) methods, which are automatically private methods.
I created a JTextField to receive what the user types. Then I created a string variable, such as:
String inputfieldinstring = inputtext.gettext().Tostring();
Then I turned into an integer variable:
int inputValueInteger = Integer.parseInt(inputfieldinstring);

How to transfer the inputValueInInteger variable, which is within the private inputTextActionPerformed (java.awt.event.aVTEvent EvT) method for another method to process data processing?

Below, I want to take the variable called inputValueInInteger that is inside the ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt), which is a private method, and transfer to other method to do the processing. How do you do this?

````
private void inputTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String inputFieldInString = inputText.getText().toString();
        inputValueInInteger = Integer.parseInt(inputFieldInString);
        }```
````

Comment: The simple answer, which likely illustrates the fact that you haven't given us enough information, is to simply add a line right after that assignment to "inputValueInInteger", calling another method and passing that variable to that method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can declare it as a static variable:

```
public class MyFirstClass {

private static Integer inputValueInteger;

public Integer getInputValueInteger() {
    return inputValueInteger;
}

private void inputTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String inputFieldInString = inputText.getText().toString();
    inputValueInInteger = Integer.parseInt(inputFieldInString);
    }
}
```

===========================

```
public class AnotherClass {

public void somethingmethod(String something) {
    Integer inputValueInInteger = MyFirstClass.getInputValueInteger();
    // Do your other thing in the method
}
```

Alternatively you can declare a static storage

```
public class Storage {
    
    private static Map<String, Integer> storageRepresentative = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public getStoreValue(String key) {
           return storageRepresentative.get(key);
    }

    public void storeValue(String key, Integer number) {
           storageRepresentative.put(key, number);
}
```

===============

In your MyFirstClass

```
public class MyFirstClass {

    private static Integer inputValueInteger;

    public Integer getInputValueInteger() {
        return inputValueInteger;
    }

    private void inputTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String inputFieldInString = inputText.getText().toString();
        inputValueInteger = Integer.parseInt(inputFieldInString);
        //Store your values here
        Storage.storeValue("current", inputValueInteger);
        }
 }
```

=====================

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public void somethingmethod(String something) {
        Integer inputValueInInteger = Storage.getStoreValue("current");
        // Do your other thing in the method
```

}

It depends on your needs.